# Angular2: how to add/change css style in svg?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, svg, angular2-template

I have the following code to add svg to angular2 component's template:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="kiwi.svg" class="logo">
  Kiwi Logo
</object>
```

In order to add css style on the fly, I tried several ways to get  contents:

1)

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.el = this._doc.getElementsByTagName('svg');
        console.log(this.el);
    }
```

result in console: [ ]

2)

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.el = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('object');
  console.log(this.el);
}
```

result in console: null

**Question:**

Can anyone help me about how to access svg and how to change css style in typescript?

Comment: You already have the `<svg>` in the template and you're trying to add CSS to that svg, or you're trying to add the `<svg>` and then change CSS after? What's the CSS exactly?

Comment: I want to keep svg to a separate file, then use css in the template to style it. Anyway, I gave up svg and used font icon, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:
First you are not using an inline svg therefore as cited here
[Changing color of SVG which was embedded using <object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508623/changing-color-of-svg-which-was-embedded-using-object), so you won't be able to change the svg styles, such as the fill of the element. 
This is not an angular problem.

To do this in angular in a practical way I suggest creating a component which has the full svg on its html:

svg-component.html

```html
<!-- svg-component.html, where we bind some properties of the svg-->
<svg.... [style.fill]="color"/></svg>
```

svg-component.ts,

```js
// svg-component.ts, where we  map to inputs these properties for easy 
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 ...
})
export class SvgComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input color = '#fff'; 
  ...
}
```

Usage:

```
<svg-component color="#000"></svg-component>
```

.

Another idea would be to try copying the approach of icon libraries and create a font, but unless its a very large collection and you want to use fonts css properties and almost create a library I would vote against it.

Answer (score 0):

You can inserti directly in you code the `svg`

**html**:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px">
  <g>
    <path id="myId" d="..."/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**css**:

```
#myId {
  fill: red;
}
```

**typescript**: you can use Jquery

```
import $ from 'jquery';

this.el = $("#myId");
```

**EDIT:**

as commented below, you can also use `document.getElementById("myId")` without import jquery

Comment: Why import and use jQuery when Angular has its own selector engine?

Comment: Ok, you can also use `document.getElementById("myId")` as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

This question is currently lacking important detail, but it looks like another [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're in Angular template land: don't get an element and change its styles with DOM methods, use the *templating system* and *property binding*.

Since I don't know what CSS you want to add specifically, here are a few generic examples:

## Option 1

Use the `[ngClass]` binding to change a single class.

Template:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml"
        data="kiwi.svg"
        [ngClass]="kiwiClass">
  Kiwi Logo
</object>
```

Component:

```
// Reassign this as needed
kiwiClass = "logo";
```

## Option 2

Use `[ngClass]` to mediate the state of a (relatively small) class list

Template:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml"
        data="kiwi.svg"
        class="logo"
        [ngClass]="{'red': shouldBeRed, 'blue': checkShouldBeBlue()}">
  Kiwi Logo
</object>
```

And then in your stylesheet, add the styles you need to the `.red` and `.blue` classes, and the `shouldBeRed` and `shouldBeBlue` conditionals.

`[ngClass]`es are assigned based on anything that evaluates to a boolean, so those can be functions, too.

## Option 3

Use `[class.className]` to mediate the state of a (relatively small) class list

Template:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml"
        data="kiwi.svg"
        class="logo"
        [class.red]="shouldBeRed"
        [class.blue]="checkShouldBeBlue()">
  Kiwi Logo
</object>
```

Assign your styles and conditionals the same as as option 2.

Here's an interesting document on [using SVG with angular 2+](https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html).