# Changing color of SVG which was embedded using <object>

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I found only one solution on StackOverflow, but user said it didn't work for them.

So, I embedded SVG image to html:

```
<object id="help-center" type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/help_center.svg">
</object>
```

I don't understand how to change color on hover in this case.

In this snippet https://jsfiddle.net/annaolsh/3j8dmnn2/ SVG is right inside HTML and color changes on hover successfully.  How to do same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`css` styles for a `svg object` can be applied for an inline `svg` only. If you embed it using an external url with the HTML `<object>` tag, you can not use the `<style>` tag within the `document` or you can not use an external `css` file to modify the `svg` content.

If you embed an external `svg` file, you have to add the `<style>` tag within the `svg` file itself as below.

```
<svg ...>
  <style>
    /* SVG specific fancy CSS styling here */
  </style>
  ...
</svg>
```

Otherwise get the source of `svg` file and inline it on the `HTML` file and then add your css styles directly. That's why your JSFiddle example worked and your provided code sample didn't work.

You can read more about how you can style `svg` objects here.
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-11